# Moodle 2.9 localisation - support multilang tags in a custom Moodle form

Tags: php, localization, moodle

I would like to create a select element in a Moodle form that can use the multi-language tags as outlined here:

https://docs.moodle.org/28/en/Multi-language_content_filter

Thus, I would like to be able to set the select text to something like:

```
<span lang="en" class="multilang">English</span><span lang="es" class="multilang">Castellano</span>
```

And expect the Multi-language content filter to be able to display "English", as the option if the user language is English and "Castellano" if the user language is Spanish.

I have searched the Moodle forums but most posts direct me to the documentation above, which assumes that I want to create multi-language text within a course description. How can I get other text content to support multi-language tags?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use format_text(). So, when creating an array of options, instead of

```
$selectoptions[$id] = $item->name;
```

You need

```
$selectoptions[$id] = format_text($item->name);
```